# mysql syntax issue with if statment

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, syntax-error

I am having an issue with this syntax near the if statement, i keep getting 
check mysql syntax near

```
== 'purp1' and product_price==53, 13, 0) as ShipWeight
```

This is what i am trying to accomplish. Any Ideas?

```
select wp_cart66_order_items.order_id as Order_ID,
   wp_cart66_orders.trans_id as Order_Number,
   wp_cart66_orders.bill_first_name as Bill_First_Name,   
   wp_cart66_orders.bill_last_name as Bill_Last_Name,
   wp_cart66_orders.ship_first_name as Ship_First_Name,
   wp_cart66_orders.ship_last_name as Ship_Last_Name,
   wp_cart66_orders.ship_address as Ship_Address1,
   wp_cart66_orders.ship_address2 as Ship_Address2,
   wp_cart66_orders.ship_city as Ship_City,
   wp_cart66_orders.ship_state as Ship_State,
   wp_cart66_orders.ship_zip as Ship_zip,
   wp_cart66_order_items.item_number as Item_Number,
   wp_cart66_order_items.product_price as Price,
   wp_cart66_order_items.Description as OrderItemsDescription,
if(item_number == 'purp1' and product_price==53, 13, 0) as ShipWeight
from wp_cart66_orders 
inner join wp_cart66_order_items
    on wp_cart66_orders.id=wp_cart66_order_items.order_id 
where wp_cart66_orders.ordered_on between "2013-04-01 00:00:00" and "2013-04-02 23:59:59"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While browsing the docs, I can't find if mysql supports `==`, try changing it into `=`

```
if(item_number = 'purp1' and product_price=53, 13, 0) as ShipWeight
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/10343)

**UPDATE 1**

use `CASE()`

```
CASE 
    WHEN item_number = 'marley1' and product_price='12.00' THEN 2
    WHEN item_number = 'samp1' and product_price='19.50' THEN 4
    ELSE 0
END ShipWeight
```

Comment: perfect that worked by removing the double == but i am now having another issue, when i added another line i get 2 Shipweight columns, how do i add multiple lines and not get all these columns?

Comment: 'if(item_number = 'marley1' and product_price='12.00', 2, 0) as ShipWeight,
if(item_number = 'samp1' and product_price='19.50', 4, 0) as ShipWeight'

Comment: do you mean combined those two?

Comment: if i have multiple products with the same price how do i add them into 1 line so i wont have a huge script? 
do i seperate them with a commma? 
'WHEN item_number = 'hell1,cav1,marley1' and product_price='15.00' THEN 2'

Comment: use `IN` example `WHEN item_number IN( 'hell1','cav1','marley1')...)`

Comment: for example in the line above hell1, cav1, marley1 etc... ?